# A few questions: Surround Sound 5.1 for film

Tags: sound, film-sound-design, panning, dolby

1) How do I pan the sound FX, which comes behind the hero? So, in order not to distract the viewer? For example, the helicopter takes off from behind the hero and flies forward?

2) How can I further process the sound effects (eq, comp) such as street environment, shots, etc.

3) How do I pan the music for all the surround channels?
I need to share a music track into multiple tracks? (Eg, Bass, kick - center speaker, LFE?). How to decompose in the L, R front speakers and rear speakers?

4) How to pan the sound effects for the rear speakers? If the bullet is flying with a center speaker, the fact that I have to send to the rear speakers? Or only the reverb sound effect?

Thank you! (:

Comment: Please split this up in to multiple questions after verifying that similar questions have not already been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your questions relate to workflow & signalflow. Try to figure out if your Digital Audio Workstation (DAW) has the abilty to handle 5.1 bussing and panning. If so you can add 5.1 (or 5.0) busses to your session and send a mono track to the surround bus. On the mono track you would see a panner which let you pan between L C R Ls Rs.
Things like panning stereo to 5.1, we call that upmixing. There are some nice techniques to use ,but upmix plugins do a nice jobs these days. Your choice. I hope this helps you a little bit in your surround sound quest ;)

Comment: Thank you so much! My choice is Waves 360 surround plugins bundle. I edit a movie in Premiere + Audition CC. The Audition is a great tool for working with surround sound!

Answer (score 0):

1.I'm not experienced with surround mixing but a few ideas: Unless you've got overhead channels such as Dolby Atmos the helicopter is going to go either left or right. As for whether you think it's distracting, only you can judge this.

2 I'm not sure what you mean here? Either audio needs processing or it doesn't. You ears should tell you this. You would use eq compression on effects if it needs to have more impact or to separate frequencies from other fx. You would only process atmos layers to reduce unwanted noise otherwise leave it.

3 I'm not sure about this one. But if the music is stereo then I don't see how you could pan it 5.1 the music would have to be mixed in surround.

4 I'd imagine like the helicopter you would have to pan it left or right. But 'bullet-by' would go down the centre as it wouldn't make sense, as it wouldn't be Bullet-by. If it was me the gunshot would be in the centre then the bullet-by left or right.

Ultimately your limited with 5.1 considering what you want to achieve.